# Sql de cidades e estados do mundo

Tags: java

Olá, boa noite.

Tudo bem ?

Eu estou fazendo três JComboBox em java. Uma para nacionalidades, cidades e estados. Eu preciso de todas as cidades e estados do mundo. Eu achei no github essa lista https://github.com/bajaj04/cities-states-countries/blob/master/cities-states-countries.sql. Porém só tem estados e cidades do Brasil. Alguém sabe uma fonte para conseguir essas informações ?

Obrigada.

Abraços.

Comment: Cidades e estados de todo o mundo?

Comment: Nem todos os países possuem estados. Mas quanto as cidades dá uma olhada nesse [http://www.geodatasource.com/world-cities-database/free](http://www.geodatasource.com/world-cities-database/free)

Comment: Isso mesmo FábioArsénio

Comment: No link que você passou a lista está em Português, não?

Comment: Eu corrigi a pergunta, está sim. Porém só estados e cidades do Brasil.

Comment: Dei uma olhada, obrigada pela dica. Mas as cidades estão em inglês.